# How to reroute grounding system to a grounding rod?

Tags: electrical, grounding

I'm building a ham radio room and need to ground my coaxial cable and antenna. If you are not a radio ham, you might not understand but it does not matter. All the resouces I can find online tells me to pound in a new grounding rod for my ham radio antenna and bond it to the existing home utility grounding rod. However, I am 100% sure that my house either don't use a grounding rod(the ground goes back to the utility company's transformer) or use a ufer ground(grouding rod inside stucco). In either of these cases:

1. How do I wire a lighting ground for my ham radio room.
2. Is it possible to reroute the grouding system to a grounding rod?
3. Do I need an electrician for step 2 or I can DIY it myself.
4. Someone on Reddit told me it is good to have a pair of grounding rods, but isn't that against the electric code if you don't bond all grounds?

For your reference, I put a picture of my house's electric/breaker panel, and you can see their is no visible grounding rod.[image]

Comment: Can you find your Grounding Electrode Conductor anywhere in the house? (It's a copper wire, usually bare, that runs from the ground electrodes up into the main panel or meter base.)

Comment: That would be behind the panel.... don't want to mess around with AC stuff without electrician though. But too expensive to call in an electrician for this.

Comment: It has to exit the panel to reach the grounding electrode...

Comment: This appears to be older construction.  There may be no ground rod at all, it may be hidden/buried, or may be bonded to a water pipe.  Where is your antenna located and what type is it?  In most cases you will want to use one or more ground rods right at the antenna for RF grounding purposes.  There should also be a coax ground near the point where the wire enters your home/shack.  That one should be bonded to your home ground if possible.

Comment: The water pipe is probably the ground rod, it is usually connected within 5’ of entering the foundation and is probably coming up through the crawl space or wall.  Ufer is not to the stucco’s but to the foundation or slab connecting to 1/2” rebar that is at least 20’  or 20’ of #4 copper wire embedded in the concrete. , if your ham room is on the other side of the house you may want a dedicated communications ground especially if you are setting up a beam antenna (for lightning protection).

Comment: If this is a condo, then what you are allowed to do with electrical is going to be limited.  Make sure you know what the rules are.

Comment: You might want to post this on ham.stackexchange.com, where ham radio folks hang out.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this should have been posted on/moved to [ham.se].

Comment: Unfortunately, this is too old for the mods to migrate. OP, please consider asking again on ham.stackexchange.com.